# How to get GridViewRow from DataKeys

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I know this type of question is asked before but no one got the answer yet...!!

How to get a Grid View Row from Data Keys.I don't want to iterate through the whole gird view.
I want to access specific text box(s) in a grid view.

for example in a 100 rows grid view i only want to disable any 2 text boxes on Page Load.
I have Data Key Names defined in grid, but how to get rows from it ?
any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following code..

```
protected void GVSample_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{   
    //Get data row view
    DataRowView drview = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {       
        //Find textbox control
        TextBox txtname = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtName");
        string Name = txtname.Text;

        if (((GridView)sender).DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString() == "Leave")
        { 
            txtname.disable=true;
        }
        else 
        { 
            txtname.disable = false; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My friend i don't know the Row index, i only know the DateKey..based on this i want to find the row..!! other wise your code is perfect if row is known.

Comment: you know datakeys that means the id for which you want the textbox?

Comment: DataKeyNames property of GridView..each GridViewRow is bonded with this Key..is it cleared ?

Comment: yes i know :)  just for instance on which criteria you want to disable text box i like to know that

Comment: See, actually its Time Sheet..after it is loaded, i want to disable the text boxes where the employee has taken vacations..so the Time Sheet Submitter can not edit these Text boxes.

Comment: Thanx for idea :) i forget to use RowDataBound Event..My problem is solved(as i was already using this event , i just added this check as you said)..But the actual question remain same :s..i wish their may be way to do that way..:)